# Disable MatPlotLib warning when using pyplot.imshow

Tags: matplotlib

First time here! I get the following warning when I use the **pyplot.imshow** function:

*"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."*

I know this is a completely expected behavior, given my data. How do I turn this warning off? I have tried

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

which should turn off all warnings, but for some reason it doesn't help with this particular warning.

Please let me know if this is a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `with warnings.catch_warnings()`?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to use that. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I would recommend getting rid of the *cause of the warning*  instead of the warning itself. Matplotlib will clip the data anyways. So the obvious solution to this is to clip the data beforehands.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the cause is definitely a wise approach. However, I would still like to know how to deal with the warning itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
import warnings

# do all your preprocessing here...

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # ...do only the stuff that causes warnings here...

# do everything immediately after here...
```

I am not sure if this will work (I would have liked it as a comment, but you can't do code blocks in comments)

edit: After trawling through the `matplotlib` code, I think the reason the above doesn't work is that it is not, in fact, a warning, but rather a log message. Accordingly, the correct interface to use is the `logging` one.

New solution:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
old_level = logger.level
logger.setLevel(100)

# plotting code here

logger.setLevel(old_level)
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, but it didn't work. Is it perhaps that the message is not actually classified as a warning?

Comment: @hehe_ty_men I went through the source code and found where the message was actually generated; yes, it's not a warning, but a log message. Have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Tried the code, it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem; please accept my answer if it worked! @hehe_ty_men